# Can I build a software around Gearman in 2015?

Tags: message-queue, gearman

I'm looking for a queue/job tool and Gearman would perflectly fit my need.

However development seems stalled:

- Last release was 1.5 year ago: https://launchpad.net/gearmand/+download
- Last commit by maintainers as well: https://code.launchpad.net/gearmand

Maintainers seems to have will to [start again](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/KPS-428BR3w) but it seems nothing really happened since Apr 23rd either.

So is that a good idea to start using gearman now (ie. it's stable enough and stalled developments is not much an issue) or what is the alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully yes. I received a notification yesterday saying that [the proposal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand/+bug/1179316) I submitted two years ago is accepted and that it will be [merged soon](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand/+bug/1179316/comments/2).